# Unable to connect to Informix db2

Tags: c#, .net, db2, informix, fluent-migrator

Unable to connect to Informix db2 from Fluent Migrator (.net/c#) on the local instance. (Windows 10 running on AWS EC2)

Getting this after invoking the migrator executable:

[+] Beginning Transaction

!!! ERROR [HY011] [IBM] CLI0126E  Operation invalid at this time. SQLSTATE=HY011

I am able to connect to the db instance via the dbaccess cli utility.
I also tried to remove all the actual migration sql statements and scripts from the migration solution and the same error happens if trying to run a totally empty migration, so the issue is likely a connection or transaction issue.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

__

More detials as requested from responses:

The connection info is this:

```
<add 
    name="Integration" 
    connectionString="Database=int_db; 
                      Server=service_144345.int.cloud:49005; 
                      User ID=int_db_user; 
                      Password=xxxxxxxx;" 
    providerName="IBM.Data.DB2"
/>
```

Both the database and the application that connects to it are located on the same  machine, which is hosted on AWS. So the connection it's trying to make is to the DB on the same box.

Comment: Have you seen this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC67398) ?

Comment: Are you using the DRDA port when connecting from .NET. Dbaccess uses the sqli protocol but any DB2 client (like the Data Server .NET Provider you must be using from Fluent) uses the DRDA protocol, so the connection details will need to have the DRDA port (or service), not the SQLI one.  You can check the sqlhosts file in the server side, the drda port should be the one with "drsoctcp"

Comment: @dsdel Running v10.5.700.375 Fix Pack 7. U figure the article refers to version pre 9.7. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting extensive logging inside the calling application the problem was narrowed down to the BeginTaansaction call. The error was caused by the absence of transaction logging on the database.

The issue was fixed by adding transaction logging to DB definition e.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE %database% WITH BUFFERED LOG;
```

Answer (score 1):

Then the Driver you are using is a DB2.NET driver that can connect to Informix server by using DRDA protocol.Make sure the port number you are using is DRDA port specified on the SQLHOST file of Informix.Unless you are using Entity Framework, I would encourage to use the Informix native .NET driver. When you use the Informix native driver it uses Informix native protocol, which is SQLI. The native driver is efficient and better supported compared to the DRDA one.When you use the native driver make sure the port you are connecting is configured for SQLI.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by Informix DB2, the Informix and DB2 are two separate database servers. Information from the error text snippet I am assuming you are using driver with DRDA protocol (likely IBM DB2 .NET or DB2 CLI).If so make sure you have enabled DRDA port on the Informix server and connect to that port.If the Informix server you are using is being provisioned from AWS, it only allow secured/encrypted connections. Then you may need do use SSL based connection after SSL setup. If you are using DRDA protocol how did you get DBACCESS working, there is lot of confusion here

Comment: Hi Satyan, the DB and the application that tries to connect to it are on the same AWS box. I added the connection info at the bottom of the question